# SignalR disallow connection

Tags: signalr

We are investigating using SignalR in our app for messaging. We want setup this messaging system as an app on its own. So our all our applications will connect to this messaging app to send messages. All this works fine but I am not sure as to how we can secure the SignalR messaging app. We only want our app to connect to it (basically our app users). If there are any other connections trying to connect, we want to reject this connection. Currently we set a query string parameter which can be validated on the server side but I am not sure how we can do our validation before the connection is made. I know in the hub we can override the OnConnected but this is too late. I want to refuse the connection before it starts.

Can someone point me in the correct directions.

Answer (score 0):

We do that in our ASP.NET application.  We have implemented an authentication module.  We validate the cookie and the user in there.

Comment: Hi Howard. Could you please explain how you have set it up. It is obvious now to me that there is no out of the package solution

Comment: We have an `IHttpModule` that we wire to `HttpApplication.AuthenticationRequest`  in the module's `Init` method. The `AuthenticationRequest` delegate either populates `HttpContext.User` and `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal` if the cookie is good or does not.  Since we decorate our Controller APIs with the `System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute`, any request without an authenticated identity fails w/ a 401.  I *believe* this is all called before the connection is established w/ SignalR because the delegate fires on all requests - but you should confirm.